# Rails Order by SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a TraitQuestion model that have a number of traits or answers - each of which has a value such as 1, 2, 3, or -3105 (for none of the above). I can't change these values because they are required for an external API.

I'd like to order them by the value, but when I do that, the answer with -3105 shows up at the top even though it says "None of the above":

```
Answer 4 = -3105
Answer 1 = 1
Answer 2 = 2
Answer 3 = 3
```

Any idea on how we could order this so that it's

```
1
2
3
-3105?
```

I'm pretty new to SQL but it seems like I should be able to do something like this:

```
@trait_question.traits.order('CASE WHEN value AS int > 0 then 1 ELSE 0 END')
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas how I can adjust the order call SQL such that it would order them in the correct order?

EDIT:
This is Postgresql 9.4.1 via Amazon AWS

Comment: you can try this way `@trait_question.traits.order('CASE WHEN value AS int > 0 then value ELSE value*(-1) END')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this will work for you or not but try this:

```
@trait_question.traits.order('ABS(value)')
```

The `ABS` will change the negative value to positive hence taking the absolute value each time. If your database field is `string` then you can do it like this as suggested by Tom which worked for him:

```
@trait_question.traits.order('ABS(CAST(value AS int))')
```

Comment: Good try but no luck :)

Comment: The above works for me on postgres 9.1.
You can also try this: 
`@trait_question.traits.order('@value')`
@ is shorthand for absolute in postgres.

Comment: This worked- my problem was that my column is a string so I had to add an additional `CAST` so `@trait_question.traits.order('ABS(CAST(value AS int))')` worked!!!

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can try this way

```
@trait_question.traits.order("CASE WHEN (value AS integer > 0) THEN value ELSE (value As integer)*(-1) END")
```

Other wise use

```
@trait_question.traits.order("abs(value AS integer)")
```

Comment: Unfortunately got a `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying > integer
LINE 1: ...rait_question_id" = $1  ORDER BY CASE WHEN (value > 0) THEN ...` error with this

Comment: hey which database you are using? it perfectly worked on the `mysql`

Comment: postgresql > Amazon AWS

Comment: It seems like the `abs(value AS integer)` should work but I now get this... `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: ...its"."trait_question_id" = $1  ORDER BY abs(value AS integer...` :(

Comment: try above option of `case` and put you complete error here

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you try to do. and I can't make a normal comment, but I'll give it a try.

can you go to your projekt folder run `rails dbconsole`

and execute

```
SELECT * FROM traitquestions ORDER BY value
```

This schould give you all entries ordered by the value, if you only want all possible values, run

```
SELECT value FROM traitquestions ORDER BY value GROUP BY value
```

if it works you can just create a method

```
def get_values
  find_by_sql "SELECT value FROM traitquestions ORDER BY value GROUP BY value"
end
```

and call this from the controller (or where ever you want)